# TypeScript enforce all files in a folder export a class which extends another class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tsc

If I have a folder:

```
jobs/
  a.ts
  b.ts
  c.ts
```

is there a way to use TypeScript so that all the files in the jobs folder export the same interface?

I'd like for a.ts, b.ts, c.ts to all export the same interface.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Do you mean that you want each of these files to have a default export that implements a particular interface?

Comment: No, there is no way to enforce that by file location alone. Each file has to `implement` an interface or `extend` a class by themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you're looking for, but you can do this:

In `jobs` directory:

`a.ts`:

```
 export interface MyInterface {
   color: string;
 }
```

`b.ts`:

```
 export interface MyInterface {
   name: string;
 }
```

`c.ts`:

```
  export interface MyInterface {
    age: number;
  }
```

Then, is some other file, you can have this:

```
 import { MyInterface } from './jobs/a';

 export class SomeClass implements MyInterface {
     color: string;
 }
```

In a different file, you can have this:

```
 import { MyInterface } from './jobs/b';

 export class SomeClass implements MyInterface {
     name: string;
 }
```

And in yet another different file, you can have this:

```
 import { MyInterface } from './jobs/c';

 export class SomeClass implements MyInterface {
     age: number;
 }
```

Unless there is a very good, bulletproof reason for this, I don't think this is a good idea at all.  It can get really easy to get confused and import/modify the wrong thing and cause yourself unnecessary headaches.

Technically, all three of the interface exports from a, b, & c could have the same parameters (like they all have `name: string`)... it's basically the same thing... maybe you're hedging against changes later?  You can extend interfaces for that FYI.

Can you further explain what you're trying to accomplish?

- EDIT *

You can't have this all in the same file:

```
import { MyInterface } from './jobs/a';
import { MyInterface } from './jobs/b';
import { MyInterface } from './jobs/c';

 export class SomeClass implements MyInterface {
     age: number;
 }

 export class SomeOtherClass implements MyInterface {
     color: string;
 }

 export class SomeOtherOtherClass implements MyInterface {
     name: string;
 }
```